# Python cumulative histogram of 2D array

Tags: python, histogram

I have the following problem. I have a 2D array of N pairs. e.g: x = [[5,2],[10,5],[3,2],...]
(so a set of arrays a = [5,10,3,...] and b= [2,5,2,...]
The first column (a) corresponds to the number of items.
The second column (b) is time taken to obtain the items in column (a).

I want to plot a cumulative histogram of the total time taken to obtain the items.
The x axis will be in bins of array (a), and the y axis should be the sum of the times from array (b) for each bin of (a). i.e. I want to plot "Nr of items"-vs-"Total time to obtain (cumulative)" as opposed to the default "Nr of items"-vs-"Nr of instances in array (a)"

I hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to be a big fan of matplotlib (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) these days.  It's got lots of built-in functionality for just about every type of plotting you'll want to do.

Here are a whole bunch of examples on how to create histograms (with images and source code available):

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html

Here's the documentation of the `hist()` function itself:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

If that's not quite what you want, you can browse the gallery and look for a more fitting plot type.  They all have source code available:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

---

Adding an example. So is this more along the lines of what you're looking for? (Not a histogram really anymore):

[image]

If so, here's the code to generate it (`x` is the sample input):

```
from pylab import *

x = [[5,2],[10,5],[3,2],[5,99],[10,22],[3,15],[4,30]]
a,b = zip(*x) #Unzip x into a & b as per your example

#Make a dictionary where the key is the item from a and the value
#is the sum of all the corresponding entries in b
sums = {}
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    sums[a[i]] = b[i] if not a[i] in sums else sums[a[i]] + b[i]

#Plot it
ylabel('Bins')
xlabel('Total Times')
barh(sums.keys(),sums.values(),align='center')
show()
```

If not, I will give up and admit I'm still not quite understanding what you want.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. Matplotlib.hist() provides a way to plot the a histogram (also allowing for the cumulative option that I am interested in) of an array (a). It does not allow me to plot the sum of the elements of (b) that fall within the bin range of (a) as the y-axis. This is what I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Any chance this is what you are talking about?

```
>>> pairs = [[5,2],[10,5],[3,2]]
>>> a, b = zip(*pairs)
>>> x = list(a)
>>> y = [reduce(lambda c, d: c+d, b[:i], 0) for i in range(1, len(b)+1)]
>>> x
[5, 10, 3]
>>> y
[2, 7, 9]
```

Here the resulting y values is the sum of all values from b up to that index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's what you want...

```
x = [[5,2],[10,5],[3,2]]  
a,b=zip(*x) #(5, 10, 3),(2, 5, 2)  
tmp = []  
for i in range(len(a)):  
    tmp.extend(b[i:i+1]*a[i]) #[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2]  
def cum(l):  
    c=0  
        for i in range(len(l)):  
            c+=l[i]  
            yield c  
y=list(cum(tmp)) #[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 62, 64, 66]  
list(zip(range(1,1+len(y)),y)) #[(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8), (5, 10), (6, 15), (7, 20), (8, 25), (9, 30), (10, 35), (11, 40), (12, 45), (13, 50), (14, 55), (15, 60), (16, 62), (17, 64), (18, 66)]
```